# API Gateway created by SAM runs locally but times out when deployed to API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Exactly as the title says. I have an API with an HTTP POST request. When I run the POST request with the API Running locally (with `sam local start-api`), it works perfectly fine. However, when I deploy it to and run it in API Gateway, I get a timeout error after 30 seconds, even though I set the max timeout to 300 seconds. My SAM file is as below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  python3.8

  Sample SAM Template for manipulation-api

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 300

Resources:

  rManipulationAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'GET, POST'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      Name: manipulation-api
      StageName: dev

  rManipulationFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: Manipulate
      MemorySize: 10000
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: <My Docker Repo>
      Events:
        Paraphrase:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /manipulate
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref rManipulationAPI
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./src/manipulate
      DockerTag: python3.8-v1

  rHealthCheckFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: HealthCheck
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: <My Docker Repo>
      Events:
        HealthCheck:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /health
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref rManipulationAPI
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./src/health_check
      DockerTag: python3.8-v1

Outputs:
  ManipulationApi:
    Value: !Sub "https://${rManipulationAPI}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/dev/manipulate"
```

Comment: You've set the Lambda function timeout to 300 seconds, but the AWS API Gateway timeout is 29 seconds and this cannot be changed. Do you really need your API calls to take up to 300 seconds, or is the timeout indicative of some other issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the API Gateway service, the API Gateway will timeout after 30 seconds regardless of what your Lambda timeout is set to.

If you expect your Lambdas execution times consistently get close to or take longer than 30 seconds, you'll need to move to more of an asynchronous pattern.

A few common patterns:

1. Client Polling: You provide two endpoints: one for submitting a request that returns instantly (i.e. `/submitRequest`) with a request ID; and another that allows a customer get the status of the request and determine if it's done and get the final result (i.e. `/getResult`).
2. Callbacks: Provide an endpoint that allows users to submit requests but also allow them to provide a URL that the service invokes when the request is completed with the results.  Or just provide an SNS topic that users can subscribe to to get the results of their request.

Regardless, API Gateway can't support 30+ second responses.  In general, it's not a good practice to design APIs that have these long waits as well since many things can happen to the connection. It's better to offer an asynchronous solution to clients which will be much less error prone.